# Bcrypt for BASH Shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, encryption, bcrypt

I'm searching for a way to hash a password using BCRYPT in a BASH script. I've searched high and low, and googled all the things ... the closest I've come is maybe an implementation using openssl, but the method is still unclear.

I am in a closed system with no external access, and python is not installed.

I am proficient at writing in BASH and am using GNU Bash, version 4.1.2(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu).

Interested in suggestions for a solution in pure BASH/AWK or any other implementation native to a common RHEL Shell.

Perl is installed, but I'd prefer to stay away from that option, least of which, I don't know Perl ... there's a social stigma associated with Perl ... (hahaha.c)

Thanks!

Comment: What is the length of the input string? What is the output hash length you want? You need to use any particular cipher to adopt?

Comment: Input string is randomly generated 7 alphanumeric characters with one of these allowed special characters   !@#$%   I've been using online hashing tools, but i'm trying to automate this process.  All I know about this process is that the java application that reads the database, where i'm updating user credentials is programmed to read BCRYPT hashed values.

Comment: So the input string is available in a shell variable?  (or) output of some other command? How are you planning to use the shell script here?

Comment: When you say "Python is not installed", does that mean installing it isn't an option here?

Comment: Yes, right now the shell is generating the random string using /dev/urandom and TR.  (tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%' < /dev/urandom | dd bs=3 count=1 2>/dev/null).  Right now I write the values to a file, so I can access the password and hash it using a tool ... I'd like to automate the hashing process so I can simply use the same script and insert my BCRYPT hashed value directly into the database.  This is a closed system and Python cannot be installed.

Comment: Right now the script is generating certificates and passwords using OpenSSL ... then I take the generated password and hash it and insert it manually -- the script is already doing everything else (i wrote the script) ... so if i can, i'd like to just hash the password using BCRYPT that is generated and stored in "$PASSWORD" and store it in "$HASHED_PASSWORD" ... and then do the insert.

Comment: I have to ask just in case. If installing python is not an option, I assume installing plain old bcrypt is not either, right?

Comment: Yes, assume I am a non-privileged user on a system so restricted it feels like I need to sudo just to breathe ....

Comment: Choose the best technology for the problem, even if that's Perl. You don't need to know Perl to have it hash a password, just like you don't need to know how to write turing machines in `sed` to substitute a string.

Comment: No bcrypt installation, no perl, no python.  I guess you can't compile C code to build your own bcrypt either?  Bash does not have bcrypt native, so you need to use something external.  Only solution I see here, perl.  You don't even have to understand the script.  From a simple google search: https://gist.github.com/evandrix/1076041 and https://yorickpeterse.com/articles/use-bcrypt-fool/ and https://www.example-code.com/perl/bcrypt_hash_password.asp.  Crazy what you can find with a little research!  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what I use

```
leo@xxx:~$ htpasswd -nbBC 10 USER topsecret
USER:$2y$10$vDtCxgJ4DIZ1itAAq6NDkedmaDFHlPdlpLY.EiEa3QBXHnH0oLatW
```

Please note the salt prefix (i.e. *$2a* or *$2y*) could be different in different system/platform.

My computer

```
leo@xxx:~$ uname -a
Linux xxx 5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: If you put this output in a file, you can match with `htpasswd -vbBC 10 <filename> USER topsecret`